# scipy minimize 'trust-krylov' doesn't seem to stop when the change reaches 'tol'

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using the trust-krylov method of scipy.optimize.minimize on a very complex minimization problem (it is far too long to post the actual code here). What I've found is that the routine runs **many** iterations far past when the differential change of the objective function between iterations drops below the 'tol' keyword I set. Let's call the objective function J and the change from iteration i to i+1 is dJ.

I understand 'tol' to mean the minimum acceptable change in objective value dJ between iterations. So if I set 'tol' to 1.e-4 as in

```
res=minimize(J,X0,method='trust-krylov', tol=1.e-4, jac=Jacobian,hessp=Hessian)
```

then I would expect the code to stop running a few iterations after dJ dips and stays below this value. However I'm running a code right now and dJ is below 1.e-8 and it is still running that way after 16 iterations and counting. Possible bug?

Answer (score 2):

**You are misunderstanding the `tol` argument.**

It's not about: `|obj_i - obj_i-1|` (calculation on scalar), but about: `||grad_i||_p` (calculation on vector).

The latter condition is often used and part of most nonlinear-optimizers (especially when no KKT-condition or second-order information is available). It also follows directly the theory: *first order necessary optimality condition for local optimal points*.

You can look at the sources:

[here: tol becomes gtol](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L464):

```
if meth in ('bfgs', 'cg', 'l-bfgs-b', 'tnc', 'dogleg',
            'trust-ncg', 'trust-exact', 'trust-krylov'):
   options.setdefault('gtol', tol)
```

[here: _minimize_trust_krylov is called](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L502):

```
elif meth == 'trust-krylov':
    return _minimize_trust_krylov(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp,
                                  callback=callback, **options)
```

[_trustregion_krylov talks about the oder conditions](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/26782d46ad2dc340eede28ded11942abfcbfd2d3/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_krylov.py#L6) and depending on `exact` / `inexact` the final optimizer is called:

```
if inexact:
    return _minimize_trust_region(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac,
                                  hess=hess, hessp=hessp,
                                  subproblem=get_trlib_quadratic_subproblem(
                                      tol_rel_i=-2.0, tol_rel_b=-3.0,
                                      disp=trust_region_options.get('disp', False)
                                      ),
                                  **trust_region_options)
else:
    return _minimize_trust_region(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac,
                                  hess=hess, hessp=hessp,
                                  subproblem=get_trlib_quadratic_subproblem(
                                      tol_rel_i=1e-8, tol_rel_b=1e-6,
                                      disp=trust_region_options.get('disp', False)
                                      ),
                                  **trust_region_options)
```

[the optimizer used](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/26782d46ad2dc340eede28ded11942abfcbfd2d3/scipy/optimize/_trustregion.py#L102) containing the following lines:

```
gtol : float
    Gradient norm must be less than `gtol`
    before successful termination.

# check if the gradient is small enough to stop
if m.jac_mag < gtol:
    warnflag = 0
    break

# check if we have looked at enough iterations
if k >= maxiter:
    warnflag = 1
    break
```

[here jac_mag is found](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/26782d46ad2dc340eede28ded11942abfcbfd2d3/scipy/optimize/_trustregion.py#L67):

```
@property
def jac_mag(self):
    """Magniture of jacobian of objective function at current iteration."""
    if self._g_mag is None:
        self._g_mag = scipy.linalg.norm(self.jac)
    return self._g_mag
```

which follows the beginning of this answer and **euclidean-norm (p=2)** is used!